# Attribute validation error for tag CFLOOP

Tags: coldfusion

Im pretty new at this coldfusion language, i did some tutorials and i just followed what the course told me to do, but im getting error on this code, someone can explain to me why?

```
<cfset carrinho=ArrayNew(1)>

<cfset carrinho[1]=StructNew()>
<cfset carrinho[1].nome="Camisa da Seleção Brasileira">
<cfset carrinho[1].valor=189>
<cfset carrinho[1].quantidade=1>

<cfset carrinho[2]=StructNew()>
<cfset carrinho[2].nome="Chuteira CR7">
<cfset carrinho[2].valor=470>
<cfset carrinho[2].quantidade=2>

<cfset carrinho[3]=StructNew()>
<cfset carrinho[3].nome="Short do Messi">
<cfset carrinho[3].valor=180>
<cfset carrinho[3].quantidade=1>

<cfdump var="#carrinho#">

<cfloop list="#carrinho#" item="name" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
        #i#:#name#
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: *but im getting error*  To help others that run into the same issue, could you please edit your question to include the actual error message as well?

Comment: I would also comment that if you are new to ColdFusion, tag-syntax makes learning the basics of the language easier, but also learn to use script-syntax. You'll find things like looping to be much easier to accomplish and follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `carrinho` is an array, not a list. You can loop it in many  different ways.

1. Way is to loop using `array` attribute

   ```
   <cfset counter=1>
   <cfloop array="#carrinho#" index="item">
     <cfoutput>#counter#. #item.nome#</cfoutput>
     <cfset counter++>
   </cfloop>
   ```

   [**DEMO**](https://trycf.com/gist/e5bbcaf9cc86f27d32700217b20fcea4/acf11?theme=monokai)
2. Using index loop with `ArrayLen`

   ```
   <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(carrinho)#" step="1" index="i">
     <cfoutput>#i#. #carrinho[i].nome#</cfoutput>
   </cfloop>
   ```

   [**DEMO**](https://trycf.com/gist/f72206358cd95050e90dc790ba4c6341/lucee5?theme=monokai)
3. Use `cfscript` `for` loop

   ```
   <cfscript>
     counter=1;
     for(item in carrinho){
       writeoutput("#counter#. #item.nome#")
       counter++;
     }
   </cfscript>
   ```

   [**DEMO**](https://trycf.com/gist/158f3f1a3f1c4fe7b28aa5b907f0daea/lucee5?theme=monokai)

These are just some ways of doing it. There are many other ways to do this.

Comment: (Update) @Diego Vinícius - Also note the difference between your example and example 1 above.  Example 1 only iterates through the elements of the array and populates `index` with the current *value*. To get both the current *element* and *position*, use the `item` AND `index` attributes. `item` will contain the current value and `index` the current *position* within the array.

Comment: RRK - I didn't notice the manual counter variable in example 1. That's a good example for CF10 and earlier. It'd be great to include a CF11+ example (like the OP is using) to demonstrate how to use both index and item attributes together :)

Comment: @Ageax Man, I feel ancient now. I was not up to date with the new `array.each()` way. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: That was Shawn :) But I hear ya... just got used to them myself.

Answer (score 4):

To build on RRK's answer and Ageax's comments:
This is how easy it is to build out an array (with a nested struct) in ColdFusion script.

Notes:

> "//" = a comment
>
> "[]" = an implicit array
>
> "{}" = an implicit struct

```
<cfscript>

  // Build the array with structs.
  carrinho = [  
    {    
        nome : "Camisa da Seleção Brasileira" ,
        valor : 189 ,
        quantidade : 1
    } ,
    { 
        nome : "Chuteira CR7" ,
        valor : 470 ,
        quantidade : 2
    } ,
    { 
        nome : "hort do Messi" ,
        valor : 180 ,
        quantidade : 1
    }
  ] ;

  // Using the counter method to determine the number     
  counter=1 ;
  for(item in carrinho) {
    writeoutput(counter & ". " & item.nome & "<br>") ; 
    counter++;
  }


  // Using each() member function
  carrinho.each(function(element, index) {
      writeOutput(index & ". " & element.nome & "<br>");

  });  

</cfscript>
```

[**DEMO**](https://trycf.com/gist/3af3aaf20ae1164f9cf9a967c5d2b8ff/lucee5?theme=monokai)

Outputs:

> 1. Camisa da Seleção Brasileira
> 2. Chuteira CR7
> 3. hort do Messi

Comment: lol you can write scripts in ColdFusion like this? i thought was only with cfloop... cfif... and that xml like stuffs

Comment: Yep. CF11+ plus brought full support for cfscript versions of all CFML "tags". These days you can write just about anything in cfscript. So do use it if you're more comfortable with it. Personally I prefer cfscript as the syntax is shorter and cleaner IMO.

Comment: If you've done programming in any other language (especially Javascript), you'll probably really like cfscript. A large reason that some of CF's poor reputation still exists is because a lot of people still think it can only be written in tags.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for you

```
<cfset carrinho=ArrayNew(1)>

<cfset carrinho[1]=StructNew()>
<cfset carrinho[1].nome="Camisa da Seleção Brasileira">
<cfset carrinho[1].valor=189>
<cfset carrinho[1].quantidade=1>

<cfset carrinho[2]=StructNew()>
<cfset carrinho[2].nome="Chuteira CR7">
<cfset carrinho[2].valor=470>
<cfset carrinho[2].quantidade=2>

<cfset carrinho[3]=StructNew()>
<cfset carrinho[3].nome="Short do Messi">
<cfset carrinho[3].valor=180>
<cfset carrinho[3].quantidade=1>

<cfdump var="#carrinho#">

<cfloop array="#carrinho#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
        #i.nome#
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

You should use array instead of list.

Comment: You may have overlooked it? That was already mentioned in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51084051/8895292) a few hours ago :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a CF10 example, that loops out the array and then uses an inner loop, to loop out the structure that represents each index of the array:

```
<cfoutput>

  <cfset carrinho=ArrayNew(1)>

  <cfset carrinho[1]=StructNew()>
  <cfset carrinho[1].nome="Camisa da Seleção Brasileira">
  <cfset carrinho[1].valor=189>
  <cfset carrinho[1].quantidade=1>

  <cfset carrinho[2]=StructNew()>
  <cfset carrinho[2].nome="Chuteira CR7">
  <cfset carrinho[2].valor=470>
  <cfset carrinho[2].quantidade=2>

  <cfset carrinho[3]=StructNew()>
  <cfset carrinho[3].nome="Short do Messi">
  <cfset carrinho[3].valor=180>
  <cfset carrinho[3].quantidade=1>

  <cfloop array="#carrinho#" index="obj">
    <cfloop collection="#obj#" item="key">
      #key#: #obj[key]#<br />
    </cfloop>
    <br />
  </cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```